# How can I get Back Projection matrix including numbers over 255 or decimal by calcBackProject?

Tags: c++, opencv, scale

I need to use *calcBackProject* and then display the exact number.

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < backProj.rows; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < backProj.cols; ++j )
        {
            cout << int(backProj.at< uchar >( i, j )) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

But its max value is 255 because of "uchar".
I tried to use

```
    Mat backProj( slid_.rows, slid_.cols, CV_64FC1 );
```

After using *calcBackProject*, display it

```
    cout << backProj.at< double >( i, j );
```

but it does not work.

I really need the exact numbers which are bigger than 255. I don't want to use *normalize* before. Can I make it by *calcBackProject*?

If I try to **scale it down**, can this Back Projection matrix includes decimal? Because I don't want that 0 exists in this matrix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I wrote my own function to get Back Projection. Hope it can help you who have same problem.

```
float ReadValueFromHist( const Mat& hist, const int x, const int y ) const
{
    int indexAlpha = int( mat.at< Vec4b >( x, y )[ 3 ] ) * bins / 256;
    return hist.at< float >( indexAlpha, 0 );
}

void CalcBackProj()
{
    backProj = Mat( mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_32FC1);
    for ( int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j )
        {
            backProj.at< float >( i, j ) = ReadValueFromHist( hist, i, j );
        }
    }
}
```